# Date Checking (COBOL)

Tags: cobol

As part of an assignment I need to create a "shipping" program that checks a certain field which tells the date an item is to be shipped. Any record with a date greater than 6 months away is to be omitted while sorting the rest of the data.

The problem is no matter what I try I get bad results. I figured an `EVALUATE` statement would be the best route to go, but I just can't seem to get it right. This is what I have down:

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
       COPY ORDERS-FILE-NEW-IN.COP.
   FD  ORDERS-FILE-NEW-IN.
   01  ORDERS-RECORD-NEW-IN.
       05  PART-NUMBER-N-IN        PIC X(8).
       05  QUANTITY-N-IN           PIC 9(4).
       05  REQUEST-DATE-N-IN.          
           10  REQUEST-YEAR-N-IN   PIC X(4).  
           10  REQUEST-MONTH-N-IN  PIC XX.   
           10  REQUEST-DAY-N-IN    PIC XX.   
       05  CUST-NUMBER-N-IN        PIC X(5).
       05  CUST-ORDER-NUMBER-N-IN  PIC X(10).   
       05  STOCK-AVAILABLE-N-IN    PIC X.
       COPY ORDERS-FILE-PRIOR-IN.COP.
   FD  ORDERS-FILE-PRIOR-IN. 
   01  ORDERS-RECORD-PRIOR-IN.
       05  PART-NUMBER-P-IN        PIC X(8).
       05  QUANTITY-P-IN           PIC 9(4).
       05  REQUEST-DATE-P-IN.          
           10  REQUEST-YEAR-P-IN   PIC X(4).  
           10  REQUEST-MONTH-P-IN  PIC XX.   
           10  REQUEST-DAY-P-IN    PIC XX.   
       05  CUST-NUMBER-P-IN        PIC X(5).
       05  CUST-ORDER-NUMBER-P-IN  PIC X(10).   
       05  STOCK-AVAILABLE-P-IN    PIC X.
       COPY ORDERS-FILE-SORT.COP.
   SD  ORDERS-FILE-SORT.
   01  ORDERS-RECORD-SORT.
       05  PART-NUMBER-S           PIC X(8).
       05  QUANTITY-S              PIC 9(4).
       05  REQUEST-DATE-S.             
           10  REQUEST-YEAR-S      PIC X(4).  
           10  REQUEST-MONTH-S     PIC XX.   
           10  REQUEST-DAY-S       PIC XX.   
       05  CUST-NUMBER-S           PIC X(5).
       05  CUST-ORDER-NUMBER-S     PIC X(10).   
       05  STOCK-AVAILABLE-S       PIC X.

   FD  ORDERS-FILE-OUT.
   01  ORDERS-RECORD-OUT           PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS      PIC X(3)  VALUE 'YES'.

   01  REPORT-START                PIC X     VALUE 'Y'.

   01  LINE-COUNT                  PIC 99    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  LINE-JUMP                   PIC X     VALUE 'Y'.

   01  PAGE-NUMBER                 PIC 99    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  MONTH-TOTAL                 PIC 99    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  YEAR-TOTAL                  PIC 99    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  YEAR-CHECK                  PIC 99    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  SPACE-LINE                  PIC X     VALUE SPACE.

   01  WS-DATE.
       05  RUN-MONTH               PIC XX.
       05  RUN-DAY                 PIC XX.
       05  RUN-YEAR                PIC XX.

   01  HEADING-LINE-1.
       05                          PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(43)
           VALUE 'OPEN ORDERS REPORT - NEXT SIX MONTHS'.
       05  HL-1-DATE.
           10  MONTH-1              PIC 99.
           10                       PIC X      VALUE '/'.
           10  DAY-1                PIC 99.
           10                       PIC X      VALUE '/'.
           10  YEAR-1               PIC 99.
       05                           PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05  PAGE-1                   PIC X(5)   VALUE 'PAGE'.
       05  NUMBER-PAGE              PIC Z9.

   01  HEADING-LINE-2.
       05                           PIC X(14)
           VALUE 'REQUEST DATE'.
       05                           PIC X(12)
           VALUE 'CUSTOMER #'.
       05                           PIC X(16)
           VALUE 'CUSTOMER ORD #'.
       05                           PIC X(10)
           VALUE 'PART #'.
       05                           PIC X(11)
           VALUE 'QUANTITY'.
       05                           PIC X(8)
           VALUE 'AVAIL'.
       05                           PIC X(5)
           VALUE 'SHIP?'.

   01  DETAIL-LINE.
       05  REQUEST-DATE.
           10  REQUEST-MONTH        PIC XX.
           10                       PIC X     VALUE '/'.
           10  REQUEST-DAY          PIC XX.
           10                       PIC X     VALUE '/'.
           10  REQUEST-YEAR         PIC X(4).
       05                           PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  CUST-NUMBER              PIC X(5).
       05                           PIC X(7)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  CUST-ORDER-NUMBER        PIC X(10).
       05                           PIC X(6)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  PART-NUMBER              PIC X(8).
       05                           PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  QUANTITY                 PIC Z,ZZZ.
       05                           PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  STOCK-AVAILABLE          PIC X(3).
       05                           PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  SHIP-MESSAGE             PIC X(4).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.
       SORT ORDERS-FILE-SORT
             ON ASCENDING KEY REQUEST-DATE-S
             ON ASCENDING KEY CUST-NUMBER-S
             ON ASCENDING KEY CUST-ORDER-NUMBER-S
             ON ASCENDING KEY PART-NUMBER-S
             INPUT PROCEDURE 200-SORT-SELECTION
             OUTPUT PROCEDURE 300-FILE-START
       STOP RUN.

   200-SORT-SELECTION.
       OPEN INPUT ORDERS-FILE-NEW-IN
                  ORDERS-FILE-PRIOR-IN

       ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE
       MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-1
       MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-1
       MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-1

       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
           READ ORDERS-FILE-PRIOR-IN
               AT END
                   MOVE 'NO' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
               NOT AT END
                   PERFORM 210-SORT-ADD-PRIOR
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM

       MOVE 'YES' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS

       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
           READ ORDERS-FILE-NEW-IN
               AT END
                   MOVE 'NO' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
               NOT AT END
                   PERFORM 220-SORT-ADD-NEW
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM

       MOVE 'YES' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS

       CLOSE ORDERS-FILE-NEW-IN
             ORDERS-FILE-PRIOR-IN.

   210-SORT-ADD-PRIOR.
       MOVE ORDERS-RECORD-PRIOR-IN TO ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
       MOVE MONTH-1 TO MONTH-TOTAL
       MOVE YEAR-1 TO YEAR-TOTAL
       MOVE REQUEST-YEAR-P-IN TO YEAR-CHECK
       ADD 6 TO MONTH-TOTAL
       IF MONTH-TOTAL > 12
           SUBTRACT 12 FROM MONTH-TOTAL
       END-IF
       EVALUATE REQUEST-MONTH-P-IN
           WHEN 01         IF MONTH-TOTAL = 1 OR
                               (MONTH-TOTAL > 6 AND < 13)
                               IF YEAR-CHECK - YEAR-1 = 0 OR 1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 02         IF (MONTH-TOTAL = 1 OR 2) OR
                               (MONTH-TOTAL > 7 AND < 13)
                               IF YEAR-CHECK - YEAR-1 = 0 OR 1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 03         IF (MONTH-TOTAL > 0 AND < 4) OR
                               (MONTH-TOTAL > 8 AND < 13)
                               IF YEAR-CHECK - YEAR-1 = 0 OR 1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 04         IF (MONTH-TOTAL > 0 AND < 5) OR
                               (MONTH-TOTAL > 9 AND < 13)
                               IF YEAR-CHECK - YEAR-1 = 0 OR 1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 05         IF (MONTH-TOTAL > 0 AND < 6) OR
                               (MONTH-TOTAL = 11 OR 12)
                               IF YEAR-CHECK - YEAR-1 = 0 OR 1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 06         IF (MONTH-TOTAL > 0 AND < 7) OR
                               MONTH-TOTAL = 12
                               IF YEAR-CHECK - YEAR-1 = 0 OR 1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 07         IF MONTH-TOTAL > 1 AND < 8
                               IF YEAR-CHECK = YEAR-1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 08         IF MONTH-TOTAL > 2 AND < 9
                               IF YEAR-CHECK = YEAR-1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 09         IF MONTH-TOTAL > 3 AND < 10
                               IF YEAR-CHECK = YEAR-1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 10         IF MONTH-TOTAL > 4 AND < 11
                               IF YEAR-CHECK = YEAR-1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 11         IF MONTH-TOTAL > 5 AND < 12
                               IF YEAR-CHECK = YEAR-1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

           WHEN 12         IF MONTH-TOTAL > 6 AND < 13
                               IF YEAR-CHECK = YEAR-1
                                   RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
                               END-IF
                           END-IF

       END-EVALUATE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the first things you should learn as a programmer, COBOL or otherwise, is to nail down what your requirements really are. Your assignment is asking to compare two dates and perform certain actions if one is 6 months or less after another. Exactly what is the meaning of 6 months? Would it be: 183 days; would it be the month number plus 6, in such case, the dates 2011-01-31 and 2011-07-01 would be 6 months apart – but 33 days short of the 183 day alternative definition; other definitions are possible too. Dates, and date arithmetic in particular, can be confusing.

Next, beware of varying date formats: YYMMDD; YYYYMMDD; MMDDYYYY; DDMMYYYY and may more. The `ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE` statement could be giving you a date format different from the one you are expecting (compile time options and/ or compiler installation defaults may affect the format). It is generally better form to request an explicit date format as in `ACCEPT WS-YYYYMMDD FROM DATE YYYYMMDD`. One of the problems in your program is related to this. You are mixing up 2 and 4 digit years, as in:

```
MOVE REQUEST-YEAR-P-IN TO YEAR-CHECK
```

Moves a 4 digit year to a two digit year. What do you suppose got truncated there? That in turn messes up your entire `EVALUATE` statement (which I recommend not using the way you have in this program).

Next I think you would be better off taking advantage of the way dates are presented to you in the input file. They are in YYYYMMDD format. All you need to do is calculate a date a date 6 months into the future from the current date and compare it directly to the date from the input file. If the input date is numerically less than the calculated date, keep the record.

Try something like:

```
       10  WS-YYYYMMDD.
           15 WS-YYYY      PIC 9(4).
           15 WS-MM        PIC 9(2).
           15 WS-DD        PIC 9(2).

   100-MAIN.
  *
  *    Calculate a reference date 6 months into the future.
  *
       ACCEPT WS-YYYYMMDD FROM DATE YYYYMMDD
       COMPUTE WS-MM = WS-MM + 6 END-COMPUTE
       IF WS-MM > 12
          COMPUTE WS-MM   = WS-MM  - 12  END-COMPUTE
          COMPUTE WS-YYYY = WS-YYYY + 1  END-COMPUTE
       END-IF
   ....
   210-SORT-ADD-PRIOR.
       IF REQUEST-DATE-P-IN < WS-YYYYMMDD
          MOVE ORDERS-RECORD-PRIOR-IN TO ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
          RELEASE ORDERS-RECORD-SORT
       END-IF
       .
```

Or something along these lines... but get rid of that huge `EVALUATE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a date is 6 months ahead I think it's easier to calculate just months

Compare

```
Year-today * 12 + month-Today + 6
```

With

```
Year-Shipping * 12 + month-Shipping
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume this is too late to help with the homework, but compares of future dates may be easier with the intrinsic **FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE**. You simply need integer compares after that.  Assuming the dates are within the range of 16010101 and 99991231 you should be good to go (Gregorian).

Answer (score 0):

```
       IF MONTH-TOTAL > 12
           SUBTRACT 12 FROM MONTH-TOTAL
       END-IF
```

Maybe you need to add 1 to the year inside that IF?
*I won't even try to write it in COBOL*

Comment: that might help a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest at the start of the program

1. you calculate the date 6 months in the future (and store in YYYYMMDD format).
2. You can then compare REQUEST-DATE-P-IN > Calculated-date

To calculate the future date:

```
 Add 6      to month
 if month > 12
    Sub 12       from month
    Add 1          to year
 end-if
```

This is much simpler than the Evaluate